# creating an object in javascript using arguments

Tags: javascript

i was reading in a book and here the code is

```
function Person(name) {

    this.name = name;
}

Person.prototype.legs = 2;

var newperson = new Person("Joe"), prop;


for (prop in newperson) {
    if (newperson.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        console.log(prop + ":" + newperson[prop]);

    }

}
```

I just want to know what is **prop*  in this

```
var newperson = new Person("Joe"), prop;
```

It is not a argument for sure so what does prop mean here. is it an optional value? thanks

Comment: `, prop;` is just the definition of the variable `prop`

Comment: Nicely obfuscated to induce headaches in newbies. Never write code like this, it just causes questions like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var newperson = new Person("Joe"), prop;
```

is equivalent to

```
var newperson = new Person("Joe");
var prop;
```

Answer (score -1):

JavaScript follows **lexical scoping** of variables.

During the **compilation** phase, JavaScript engine will only catch up the variable declarations.

So, `var newperson = new Person("Joe"), prop;` after the compilation phase both variables are stored in the scope with no difference. Both are `undefined`.

At the **execution** phase, JavaScript  will find the initialization of `newperson` as a `Person` object. `prop` is not initialized yet thus `undefined`.